# Transforming Lat/Long NASA points into raster for ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, interpolation

I have this irradiation file and I would like it to upload it in ArcMap in order to overlay it with other layers to do clips, intersections, etc?

http://eosweb.larc.nasa.gov/sse/global/text/direct_radiation

Comment: You want to interpolate the each month values on that page to a separate raster layer based on lng/lat coordinate, or just create a point layer based on the lng/lat coordinates?

Comment: Interpolate it please.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

1. Copy the data from the webpage, select the header rows (lat, lng, ...etc), then scroll to bottom of page and hold shift key and select last records, then right click and copy
2. Right click within your Windows Explorer, My Computer, or Computer and create text document
3. Open text document with either notepad or wordpad right click and paste
4. Open blank ArcMap, on dataframe/properties change projection/coordinate system to GCS_WGS_1984
5. Add the text file into ArcMap, right click and and Display XY data
6. Once you see the point event layer right click and Data>Export Data it to a filegeodatabase for better performance
7. There are a host of GIS [interpolation tools here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/An_overview_of_the_Interpolation_tools/009z00000069000000/) that you may use to interpolate the point data to get a raster(s).